# Android Smudged layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I've never seen a thing like this, my layout is just smudged on my device (Infinix Zero X506 running Android 4.4.2) however on an emulator it displays just fine, I can't figure out the cause and I haven't seen a similar question here or on Google. I am using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1
Below is an image
[image: Layout Screenshot]

Below is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:hint="@string/enter_title"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:id="@+id/edName" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/to_do_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_to_do_details"
        android:id="@+id/edDetails" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/select_priority"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spPriority"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/set_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <Button
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btDate"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/set_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btTime"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The entries in the spinner are feed from a custom adapter if that helps

Comment: Can you post the xml style for the Activity?

Comment: xml style? @Guardanis

Comment: I believe this is an issue with nine-patch images using the newest build tools/gradle plugin.

Comment: Me too facing the same issue.. :(

Comment: Me too Facing this problem... :( I am using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3 
prob. with same Version Android 4.4.2(htc desire 616 dual sim)

Comment: The problem will be solved in next release Android Studio 2.2 preview 4.

Answer (score 3):

**This is confirmed fixed with [Android Studio 2.2 Preview 4](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-4)**

So you no longer need to revert to plugin version 2.1.0 as the original answer explained.

Original Answer:

This is a problem with the alpha version of the gradle plugin. You can continue using Android Studio 2.2 if you revert the plugin version to 2.1.0, like so:

```
buildscript {

    ...

    dependencies {
        // other entries here
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }

    ...

}
```

In your root projects `build.gradle`

Please vote for the issue to be fixed on [the official bug tracker entry here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467)

Comment: Works the overall smudging is gone, Thanks, However the colors in my spinner are still not displaying correctly

Comment: Perhaps make a new post explaining that issue more clearly, as it is separate to this one and likely related to your particular code rather than the gradle plugin issue (which is fixed in 2.2 Preview 4, should become available this week sometime).