# Android UI Issue

Tags: android

Does anyone know what's the root cause of those? Following are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

It seems the all selector doesn't work on the action bar and drawer.

Comment: Did you update Android Studio lately?

Comment: Yes, and we also updated SDK from 18 > 23

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Smudged layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout)

Comment: I have installed both 2.1 and 2.2 preview version, should I need to uninstall them?

Comment: Is it happening in both android studio 2.1 and 2.2 ?

Comment: Yes, both version is happening