# EditText is not showing well

Tags: android, xml, layout

When i use EditText in my layout screen , its showing me like this

[image]

I have not applied any theme or any kind of style to activity or EditText.

Can anyone know the solution ?

Here is my Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00529B">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dip">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Member ID"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:id="@+id/txt_member_id"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/txt_mobile"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Key"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:id="@+id/txt_key"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_login" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: how are we supposed to without seeing the code ?

Comment: where is your xml file?

Comment: are you using android studio 2.2 preview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Smudged layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout)

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your gradle version to 2.1.+ (f.e.
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2')

There is a critical bug in 2.2.+ prior to alpha-4 concerning 9-patch (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467)