# Android graphical issue

Tags: android

I have a strange issue only on Android versions lower than 5. It's much more easy to explain with some photos, take a look at them.

The only error I noticed is:

> I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
>
> W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16727: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V

Here are some info from my gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
```

Same issue with 23.0.3

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you writtent your own style in style.xml?

Comment: Did you add some 9.patch files for this controls ?

Comment: No.. In fact I have this issue even when I tap on a toolbar button.. see the third photo

Comment: @MikeM. I think is the same issue.. Thanks.. I'll let you know if it solves this issue.

Comment: what styles are you using for these elements?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks very much..

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer to my own question in case someone has the same issue and finds my question before this one [Android Smudged layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout)

The problem is with **gradle 2.2**, in fact to solve it you have to modify your `build.gradle` with

```
buildscript {

    ...

    dependencies {
        // other entries here
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: All you had to do was mark the duplicate as helpful, then your question would've been linked right to that post.