# I used Floating Labels for EditText. it's works fine in Marshmallow & Lollipop. But it's does not working In kitkat(API 19) and below API level

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, material-design

[image]
    For Floating Editext labels my dependency in gradle is:  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1' what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Smudged layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using **Material Design** library as - com.android.support:design. Google introduces material design language for Lollipop (API 21) and above. So for below API 21, it will not support. You will not get same features and UI components in KITKAT.