# Android Material Design Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created new project with theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` but it is showing me distorted colors on views. [image]

My device is running Android version `4.4.2`. What will be the possible solution.

Thanks,

Comment: share your xml code of this activity

Comment: which gradle & studio plugin you are using?

Comment: Check this links - 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013163/i-used-floating-labels-for-edittext-its-works-fine-in-mashellow-lolipop-but/38013380#38013380   2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout