# Search Widget UI issue on top of Toolbar

Tags: android, android-search

Search icon and the edit text is seen properly.Earlier it was working fine in my application,not sure what is causing this kind of behavior.
Same behaviour is seen in the sample application.

Please suggest me the solution to correct this.

[image]

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolBar;
private MenuItem searchItem;

private SearchView mSearchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    setupSearchView(searchItem);

    return true;
}

private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.searchwidget.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:title="@string/app_name">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main" />
```

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:apk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="search"
    apk:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    apk:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

Comment: could be similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan... it worked.