# Older Android OS showing styling weirdly in menus / edit text / buttons

Tags: android, styling

Not really sure how to search for something like this? Anyone seen these types of styling issues in older versions of Android? Each of these three issues appear normally on current Android.

Menu's background is too small to see the two items... and there is a red outline?
[image]

The buttons highlight with a strange bezel:
[image]

The edit text is highlighted strangely:
[image]

Comment: This is a problem with 9-patch image processing in a recent release of the Android build tools. Which version of the build tools are you using (it should be in your `build.gradle` file)?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: Try changing it to "23.0.3" or even "24.0.0"

Comment: 23.0.3 fixed two of the three issues, the edit text is still off. But that helped! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Smudged layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout)