# ActionBar elements look bad in pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-support-library

I created an app from the "basic activity" template in Android Studio 2.2 preview 3. I only changed app name from the default values. The elements in the App Bar, when pressed, look bad on pre-lollipop devices. It draws some kind of weird shadow. It uses design and appcompat-v7 libs version 24.0.0

Example, on a Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, looks as expected (I link the images as I have not enough reputation to post them):

[image]

On a Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.3:

[image]

It happens also in a 2.3 device, API 18 and API 10 emulators.

I built this app because I have the same problem in another app that uses support libraries 23.4.0. There I have the same problem with an action icon and the burger (navigation drawer) icon inside a SupportActionBar.

Is there any way to make them look prettier? (I don't need ripple effect, plain backgrounds are ok).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Smudged layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622220/android-smudged-layout)

Comment: The shadows you see are the one from the 9 patch format of the image. Could you provide more code on how you are setting the buttons and the images? Also XML layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Bug of Android studio 2.2 preview which are solved in Android studio preview 4

I recommended you to update the gradle with new version

**Android studio 2.2 Preview 4**

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview4available

**or with Gradle 2.1.0**

> ```
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
> ```

Comment: This worked for both applications. I updated full Android studio to Preview 4. Thank you!